Retrieving file extension from Dataverse Image column
I am using an Image column in a dataverse table to allow a user to take a picture from a model driven app and cannot determine the image extension in a power automate flow.
Periodically, a flow will execute that retrieves all records where the image column is not null, create a file on sharepoint, and update the record with the sharepoint link. This is being done to save on dataverse storage.
To retrieve the file from dataverse, I'm using the "Download a file or image" dataverse action. This action returns the file, but does not indicate the file type.
There is also no filename value on the record with the image column (unlike the file column type, which has a filename value).
I'm wondering if anyone has encountered a similar situation and how they were able to determine the file extension for an image column.
